# не разлипается текст

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background: #000;
}
.men {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
}
.navigation {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo {
 margin-left: 40px;
}
.logo p {
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
}
.menu {
 display: flex;

}
.menu li {
 list-style: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.menu a {
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-right: 75px;
}
.menu a::last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.menu a::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 0%;
 height: 3px;
 background: #B76C24;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.menu a:hover:before {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>SITE</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header></header>

 <section>
  <!-- start menu -->
  <div class="men">
   <div class="navigation">
    <div class="logo">
     <p>Снигур Степан</p>
     <p>Верстка, Web Design</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">ОБО МНЕ</a></li>
     <li><a href="portfolio.html">ПОРТФОЛИО</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">СВЯЗАТЬСЯ</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end menu -->
 </section>

 



 <footer></footer>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Пункты меню прилипают к тексту слева. Помогает только margin. Что я только не пробовал. Float, flex и т.д. Можно ли как-то их разлепить, без ущерба в сторону адаптивности? (меню должно быть фиксированным при прокрутке)

Comment: Более развернуто, не очень понятно какой желаемый результат

Comment: Не хочу никого обидеть, но зачем создавать сайт с таким громким названием ("Я веб верстальщик"), если даже не можете сверстать такой не сложный момент..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `width: 100%` к классу  `men`.

Answer (score 0):

Если эти блоки у вас прилипают при justify-content: space-between, значит, не хватает ширины контейнера, чтобы разнести их. Попробуйте уменьшить размер шрифта, например. Или отступы между пунктами меню. (Комментарии писать не могу, не хватает 4 баллов)